# accessing a node moudule from javascript file using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js

i am building a web site using nodejs/javascipt/jquery/html/css and mysql.

lets say i have an html login page that has receives an input from the user (name && psw)
and i have a file:

```
login.js:

var node = reuqire('some module');

$(document).ready(function() {

var username = $('#name');
var password = $('#password');
 $('#login_button').click(function(){ login(username.val(),password.val())});

});
```

without the require it works fine.(i also tried to move the require into the ready function)
for some reason it does not let me use another module.
any help?

thank you :)

Comment: It looks like you're mixing client-side/server-side JavaScript in one file. `require` is Node, `$(document).ready` is jQuery. (Also, you spelled `require` incorrectly.) What are you trying to accomplish? Requiring a Node (server-side) module at the client-side?

Comment: i am trying to access my database to see if the user and password are correct.
so i have a js file that connects to the database(using my sql) and supplies a bunch of functions for different things to do in database. one of them to see if he exists..

Answer (score 0):

Calling server-side functions in a client-side file like that is not possible. However, looking at your comment I suggest the [NowJS](http://www.nowjs.com/.) library.

NowJS does not allow you to mix client-side/server-side JavaScript in one file (because that just does not make sense, and if it did it would be a high security risk). But it does allow you to define a function server-side (which will e.g. check credentials), which you can call client-side with no additional hassle. When that server-side function is done you can send a client-side function with the result (i.e. correct/wrong credentials). That way you can achieve what you want rather easily.

If you've read the basic tutorials, you could implement it like this (partly pseudocode since I don't know how you're checking login details etc.):

At the server-side:

```
everyone.now.checkLogin = function(username, password, callback) {
  db.query("...", function(results) {
    if(results.correct) {
       callback(true);
    } else {
       callback(false);
    }
  });
};
```

At the client-side:

```
$("#login_button").click(function() {
  var username = $("#username").val(),
      password = $("#password").val();

  now.checkLogin(username, password, function(correct) {
    if(correct) {
      $("#correct_message").show();
    } else {
      $("#wrong_message").show();
    }
  });
});
```